# Hg ssh redirect

Tags: apache-2.2, ssh, mercurial

We would like to transfer HG traffic from one server to another. Because we are using DNS alias which we need to keep for another purposes.

We need to redirect requests for cloning/checkouting etc. HG repos - example:

```
hg clone ssh://hg@dns-alias/project/repo
```

And we would like to use the same URL in future. Because of that we need to transfer traffic via forwarding, apache etc. Do you have any suggestions how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a different DNS name, and make all the repo users switch.

It will be only a minor pain for everyone who uses the Mercurial repo, and it will be a completely smooth migration on your end.